Gradle run/build issue while trying to run an android app
Could not run phased build action using connection to Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.6-all.zip'.
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.gradle.api.internal.catalog.GeneratedClassCompilationException: No Java compiler found, please ensure you are running Gradle with a JDK
org.gradle.api.internal.catalog.GeneratedClassCompilationException: No Java compiler found, please ensure you are running Gradle with a JDK
No Java compiler found, please ensure you are running Gradle with a JDK
Error code i'm getting, I'm not sure what the problem is. I've set the JAVA_HOME path and path to jdk 22 and it still won't build.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

i also found same issue  try with below steps

Check JDK Installation by cmd java -version
Verify JDK in Gradle Configuration
IDE Settings
Check Gradle Wrapper Version
Clean and Rebuild
Verify System Path
Check System Requirements

